# Can we run containerized Azure Functions with local SQL Server as the AzureWebJobsStorage?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have Azure Logic Apps running in a Docker container, is it possible to use a local SQL Server as the storage for AzureWebJobsStorage instead of Azure Storage?

I know I can do it for development environment using AzureStorage Simulator, is there any alternative for production environments?

Comment: Is it a logic app or a function app ?

Comment: This is a logic app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know I can do it for development environment using AzureStorage
> Simulator, is there any alternative for production environments?

No, you cannot do this in a production environment. In the development environment, you are actually simulating Azure Storage based on sql server. This is not possible in a production environment.

Have a look of this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#differences-between-the-storage-emulator-and-azure-storage

(They are also different in some characteristics.)